# IMG tag in HTML document not working (image without suffix)

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to insert [this](http://img.netaffiliation.com/c/29/27601/427/photo_752760113427g) image:

in one of my html documents with this kind of basic code:

```
<img src="http://img.netaffiliation.com/c/29/27601/427/photo_752760113427g" style="border: 1px solid" />
```

EDIT: I uploaded the code [here](http://www.finder-auto.fr/test.html)

However this does not work. 
Here are what my investigations gave me:

- The file is not served on one of my servers. I cannot change the filename or anything
- When I execute 
  `curl -I http://img.netaffiliation.com/c/29/27601/427/photo_752760113427g` , it correctly gives me Content-Type: image/gif
- It seems my code works on Firefox but I have no success on Chrome or Safari (on Mac Os X).

Does someone ever had this problem or knows the solution?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: I changed the img tag but still does not work except on Firefox

EDIT 2: I confirm what was commented before, this works properly on Chrome/IE/Firefox on Windows7... It just won't work on Mac OS X...

FINAL EDIT: Ok I found the solution by myself !!!
The problem was coming from... Adblock !  Can't believe it... I just had to unblock the domain of the image and it's working ok now.

Comment: Stupid question of course, but if the image is an animated gif, have you checked if you have image animations enabled in all browsers? I have seen situations where a gif's first frame was blank and people thought it wasn't loading properly.

Comment: @MrLister: well yes if I try to load an animated gif into Safari, I see the animation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Davids answer about the faulty use of  `</img>` tag.

However, I could render the image with your code snippet in both Chrome and Firefox, so I suspect there might be other errors in your code blocking the image?

If fixing the image tag does not work, give the HTML Validation Service a go to discover any other problems:

[HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I fixed the source to go through HTML validator. Now it's validated by HTML Validation Service.
However on my system the image is still not displayed except on firefox. I guess it's something to do with MacOs X ??

Comment: @EagleOne And if you load the image into Safari directly by pasting its URL into the location bar?